# Only output the name of file containing a pattern (without the line output) using grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression, file-search

I want to list the files that contain a pattern,
without outputting the line(s) containing the pattern. 
I assume that it's possible to do this with `grep`. 
How should I use `grep` in that sense? 
For example, the following command
gives all the lines containing "stringpattern" (case insensitive)
in all the `.txt` files. 
I want to have only the name of the file (± the line number).

```
grep -ni stringpattern *.txt
```

Ideally, if the string/pattern is present more than once in one file,
I would like to have multiple lines of output for that file.

Comment: And if the string is present more than once in one file? Do you want the output to show multiple lines for that file (each line with the same filename, but a different line number), or one line with the filename and the line numbers concatenated?

Comment: many thanks for your comment @Edward. Yes ideally i would like to have multiple lines for that file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need only files that match:

```
grep -lie pattern -- *.txt
```

I don't think that you can use only grep to print only files and line numbers, because with option `-n`, it outputs on every line 'file:line:match'. If the file names don't contain `:` nor newline characters, you can though pipe this to `cut` to get only what you want.

```
grep -nie pattern -- /dev/null *.txt | cut -d: -f 1,2
```

The `/dev/null` is needed for the case where `*.txt` expanded to only one filename where `grep` then would otherwise not print the file name. With the GNU implementation of `grep` or compatible, you can use the `-H` / `--with-filename` instead to ensure the file name is always printed.

Comment: At least as long as the filenames don't contain colons, but in that case the output of `grep -n` is ambiguous anyway, sigh. Something like `awk '/pattern/ { print FNR, FILENAME }' *.txt` could also perhaps be used. (Still ambiguous if the names have newlines, sigh^2)

Comment: Indeed @ilkkachu it also works well. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/pattern/{print FILENAME}' *.txt
```

Comment: Indeed @PraveenKumarBS it also works well. many thanks